# Magento 2: Add resources to module and use them in template?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, skin

Where do I have to add **js, css, and images** in my module?

In Magento 1 I had an image stored in

> */skin/frontend/base/default/black/Newsletter2Go/img/ajax-loader.gif*

where do I have to put it in Magento 2 and under which path is this image accessible afterward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your static resources under

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/[js|css|images]

and you can access image in phtml file like this.

```
$this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images-folder/imagename.extension');
```

after that do `php bin/magento s:s:d -f` if the image does not show up.

Comment: I tried it like this `$this->getViewFileUrl('Black_Newsletter2Go::img/ajax-loader.gif');`, this is the link it gave `http://www.example.net/pub/static/version1568797929/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/Black_Newsletter2Go/img/ajax-loader.gif`. I get 404 not found.

Comment: DId you add ajax-loader.gif under `Black/Newsletter2Go/view/frontend/web/img` ??

after that do php bin/magento s:s:d -f

Comment: Yes the file is in this location. I try the command in a moment and report back.

Comment: Okay if it works accept the answer so it will help to other.